# Idiomatic way of saying "X-type zombie" where X is the name of someone?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> The game developers added an Elvis-type zombie into the game. The
> zombie rocks an Elvis wig and attacks the player by using voice
> attacks.

I am not sure if this is how most writers would phrase it. Is there a better way to phrase this particular sentence?

Comment: Earlier writers may have used "Elvis-like", but in the context of modern game documentation "Elvis-type" is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name in question is a very famous one, so that readers will immediately understand what is meant, then it's a succinct way to evoke an image. The first name of Elvis Presley qualifies in this regard.

Comment: It's recognizable enough that it can stand on its own as an adjective: _an Elvis zombie!_